# How to run sqlplus on oracle via R

Tags: r, oracle, sqlplus

I am running SQL-code on a oracle database. Some commands require to run them via sqlplus. Is there a way to avoid my commandline solution but directly running sqlplus via, e.g. `dbSendStatement()`.

Pseudo code to not share any sensible information

```
# Via dbSendStatement ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
con <- odbc::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                       Driver = "oracle",
                       Host = "HOST", 
                       Port = "PORT",
                       SVC = "SVC", 
                       UID = Sys.getenv("USRDWH"),
                       PWD = Sys.getenv("PWDDWH"),
                       ssl = "true",
                       timeout = 10)
# Error
odbc::dbSendStatement(con, "EXEC SQL CODE")
# actual error message:
#> Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement, immediate) : 
#>   nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1594: 00000: [RStudio][OracleOCI] (3000) Oracle Caller Interface: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement


# Via system command -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cmd <- paste0("sqlplus ", 
              Sys.getenv("USRDWH"), "/", Sys.getenv("PWDDWH"), 
              "@", "HOST", ":", "PORT", "/", "SVC", " ",
              "@", "EXEC script.sql")
cmd
#> [1] "sqlplus USR/PWD@HOST:PORT/SVC @EXEC script.sql"

# Works
system(cmd,
       intern = TRUE)
```

Comment: Code like that always connects directly to the database. `sqlplus` is a specific client tool; it doesn't have its own API for those kind of interactions. If your SQL commands cannot be adapted, then you will need to write a shell interaction to manipulate `sqlplus` as you did with `cmd`. That said, this implementation is *very* insecure, as it will allow *anyone* with  access to your host to see the database username and password associated with the process while it is running.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. If I understand you correctly it is basically impossible in the desired way. If so, please feel free to post your comment as an answer since it answers my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code like that always connects directly to the database. `sqlplus` is a specific client tool; it doesn't have its own API for those kind of interactions. In other words, you always connect to the database; you can't connect *to* `sqlplus` as it is not a service.

Your *best* option would be to convert your SQL in such a way that you can run it natively in your code using a direct database connection (i.e. don't use `sqlplus`). If your SQL commands cannot be adapted, then you will need to write a shell interaction to manipulate `sqlplus` as you did with cmd in your example.

That said, this implementation in your example is *very* insecure, as it will allow *anyone* with access to your host to see the database username, password, and connection info associated with the process while it is running. There are much more secure ways of scripting this, including the use of an auto-open [Oracle Wallet](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/secure-external-password-store-10gr2) to hold the credentials so you don't have to embed them in your code (which is *always* a bad idea, too).

Using Oracle Wallet, your `cmd` call would then look more like this:

```
sqlplus /@TNS_ALIAS @EXEC script.sql
```

This is still not perfect, but is a step or two in the right direction.